# Можно ли использовать только primary key в MySQL таблице?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Дана MySQL БД для хранения анкет и результатов их заполнения.

1. Таблица `answer` хранит ответы на вопросы анкет.
2. Таблица `user_profile` хранит ответы на вопросы профиля пользователя.
3. Таблица `user` хранит только id для связи `user_profile` и `answer`.

Мне нужно разграничить ответы на вопросы анкет и ответы на вопросы профиля пользователя. Поля в `answer` и `user_profile` как видно на модели почти идентичны. Я хочу связать `user_profile` с `user` также как `user` связана `answer` (many to one). Я хочу избавиться от полей `name`, `email`, `tel` и т.д. из таблицы `user` и оставить только `id` (PK).
Правильно ли будет использовать таблицу user, в которой будет только primary key (PK) и ничего больше для связи user_profile и answer? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно часто таблица определяет тип данных, а строки в ней значения этого типа. Если в вашей системе есть вырожденный пользователь (у которого есть только id), то логично создать таблицу с единственным столбцом id (по которому будет построен первичный ключ).

В реальных системах таких таблиц обычно не бывает, так как у пользователей находятся какие-нибудь атрибуты типа логина или даты регистрации. Однако, если у пользователя кроме id действительно ничего нет, то использовать такую таблицу можно и нужно.

Непонятно только почему вы ответы на вопросы анкет и ответы на вопросы профилей разделили в разные таблицы. Да ещё и назвали *ответы* `user_profile`. Кажется тут что-то не так.

По идее, ответы это ответы. Чтобы их отличать, надо знать на какие вопросы они были заданы. Чтобы различать вопросы, надо знать, где они были заданы. Соответственно, чтобы разделить ответы по тому на откуда заданные вопросы они были даны, надо сджойнить к ответам вопросы, и места откуда эти вопросы были заданы. Это довольно неудобно и можно денормализовать схему, добавив вопросам столбец **тип вопроса**, со значениями **вопрос анкеты** и **вопрос профиля** (`type enum('questionnaire', 'profile') not null`), тогда всё станет немного проще.

Я тут подумал, анкета может переводиться как профиль, а таблицы анкеты в вашей диаграмме нет. Вы точно понимаете, что и как хранится в этой базе? Кажется, что таблица user_profile хранит анкеты, а не ответы.

Comment: Понимаю, ведь я ее проектировал, хоть у меня и мало опыта. На самом деле сейчас эта БД выглядит таким образом: https://i.imgur.com/fYAH7WE.png.
Ранее у пользователя кроме `id` были: `name`, `email`, `tel` ... Эти поля образовывали профиль пользователя. Я решил отказаться от них в пользу отдельной таблицы `user_profile`, так как мне пришлось сильно расширить список вопросов для заполнения профиля пользователя. Таким образом, `answer` содержит ответы на вопросы анкеты, а `user_profile` ответы на вопросы нужные для заполнения профиля пользователя. Я решил не использовать `answer` для этого.

Comment: В конкретном случае пользователь нужен только для связи между ответами и самим пользователем. Анкеты хранит [survey](https://i.imgur.com/fYAH7WE.png)
Похожий вопрос и ответ, который показывает примерно то, что мне нужно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951686/is-a-one-column-table-good-design/951817#951817) .

Comment: Кажется я понял. Вы делаете какой-то опросник, в начале (или в конце) которого пользователь вводит какие-то личные данные. И запрос личных данных тоже решили сделать как вопросы. Типа: "Как вас зовут?". Правильно?

Comment: Да! В начале пользователь заполняет пару десятков вопросов (ФИО, телефон, эл. почта, должность и так далее), которые я называю профилем пользователя (`user_profile`). Затем выбирает анкеты и заполняет их (`answer`). То есть у разных пользователей могут быть заполнены разные анкеты (`survey`). Но у всех пользователей всегда заполнен "профиль". У пользователя нет логина и пароля. Пользователь нужен только для связи ответов на вопросы.

Comment: _Можно денормализовать схему, добавив вопросам столбец тип вопроса, со значениями вопрос анкеты и вопрос профиля_
Действительно. Не знаю почему я не додумался. Тогда делаю дроп таблицы `user_profile` и добавляю новый столбец. Правильно я понял, что это ManyToOne (`question_type_id`) отношение к таблице `question_type`?

Comment: Да, вы поняли верно.

Comment: Я создал похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1010776/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82) относящийся к этой же БД. Поможете?