# Как сохранять ответы пользователей на открытые вопросы анкеты (заранее не подготовленные)?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, rest, mysql-workbench

Проектирую MySQL базу данных для хранения анкет и ответов пользователей на вопросы этих анкет. На основе данных из базы формируется JSON. Разрабатываем REST API.

Пользователь заполняет данные (`name`, `email`, `position`, `tel`...) и таким образом получает `user.id`. Затем отвечает на вопросы (таблица `question`) анкет (таблица `survey`). В результате ответы пользователя сохраняются в таблице `answer`.

Ответ пользователя может быть заранее подготовлен в таблице `options` (вариант выбора, например тэг `select`). А может быть не подготовлен. Поэтому кроме таблицы `answer_options`, которая содержим выбранные пользователем варианты ответов (многие-к-многим) таблица `answer` содержит поля:

- `text` (ответ на вопрос как текст),
- `num` (ответ на вопрос как число),
- `yn` (ответ на вопрос как логический тип).

Таблица `input_types` содержит тип элемента формы (например, `<input type="text"/>`.
Таблица `insert_types` содержит имя поля в таблице `answer` (`yn`, `text`, `num` или `options`).
API выводит вопрос в таком виде:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Годовой оборот компании?",
    "placeholder": "Введите число",
    "required": true,
    "input_type": {
        "name": "text"
    },
    "insert_type": {
        "name": "num"
    }
}
```

Фронт смотрит `insert_type` и может отправить такой объект ответа на вопрос:

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "question": 1,
    "num": 100
}
```

API читает объект и сохраняет в таблице `answer` (свойство `num` сохраняется в `answer.num`)

Мне не нравится то, что фронту приходится смотреть `insert_type`. Как принято сохранять ответы пользователей на открытые вопросы анкеты (заранее не подготовленные)?
[image: Модель БД для опросов]

Comment: *таблица answer содержит поля:

text (ответ на вопрос как текст),
num (ответ на вопрос как число),
yn (ответ на вопрос как логический тип).* Смысл? Число прекрасно хранится как текст. Булево значение прекрасно хранится как число, котороехранится как текст. Так что нафиг три поля - поле текстового значения и поле типа (как интерпретировать).

Comment: @Akina, понимаю. Но даже если я избавлюсь от `yn` и `num`, оставив только `text`, все равно потребуется `insert_type`, так как нужно будет выбирать между `options` и `text`

Comment: Не, а я что сказал? по-моему, я очень вменяемо назвал количество полей - два,- и назначение каждого поля: "поле текстового значения и поле типа".

Comment: @Akina, правильно я понял, что `insert_type` и тому подобное не избежать? Ведь если полей больше одного, то все равно нужно сообщать фронту о том в какое поле передавать данные

Comment: *правильно я понял, что insert_type и тому подобное не избежать?* Ну почему? поле текстовое... первый байт кодирует тип, остаток является результатом. Вот только оно тебе надо? геморроиться каждый раз с упаковкой да дешифровкой...

Comment: @Akina, то есть моя модель БД и в частности `insert_type` - это нормальное решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ пользователя это какое-то значение. То, как это значение интерпретировать, зависит от вопроса. Фронт может всегда отправлять совершенно одинаковый для любых случаев запрос с ответом:

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "question": 1,
    "answerValue": "100"
}
```

Ответ пользователя стоит хранить в том виде, в котором он от пользователя получен (строкой). Затем это значение можно интерпретировать в зависимости от типа вопроса. Например, на вопрос о готовом обороте можно ответить `100млн`, `100m`, `100 * 10^6`. Разбираться с тем что имел ввиду пользователь надо на этапе анализа его ответа.

Однако, для построения правильного интерфейса на фронт надо отдавать тип инпута. Не стоит зацикливаться на типах инпутов HTML-форм (но посмотрите на [современные типы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)), используйте те, которые имеют смысл в вашем опроснике.

Итого:
Тип хранится в вопросе; Ответ -- просто строка; При необходимости интерпретировать ответ, смотрим тип вопроса и делаем выводы.

Comment: _Тип хранится в вопросе_ - вы про `input_type`? _Ответ -- просто строка_ - а если это _id_ заранее подготовленного ответа из таблицы `options`? Имеете ли вы в виду, что нужно получать ответ в виде строки в любом случае, и, если, например, `"input_type": "select"`, то рассматривать эту строку как _id_? Затем размещать в нужное поле? Пока не очень понимаю.

Comment: Кажется я разобрался :) Вы имеете в виду, что можно избежать сохранения id варианта ответа и всегда сохранять строкой? То есть вопрос, например, "Выберите свой возраст из списка" выводит `options`. Нужно просто сохранять выбранное пользователем значение строкой (а не так, как в моей БД реализовано сейчас - сохраняется `id` варианта ответа). Но имеет ли право на жизнь реализованный мной вариант с `insert_types`?

Comment: @ОлегНечаев конечно имеет. Просто каждый новый тип будет немного сложнее добавлять.

Comment: спасибо! _Вы имеете в виду, что можно избежать сохранения id варианта ответа и всегда сохранять строкой?_ - а это я правильно понял?

Comment: В строке может быть id варианта ответа. Просто то, что это id будет ясно из типа вопроса. Например, для вывода ответов пользователя получаем все ответы с вопросами, для всех вопросов типа _select_ выбираем варианты ответов, и потом выводим, меняя id на значение соответствующего варианта.